# Want to execute one time .Net 6.0 Console App using installer

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-installer, url-scheme

I want to provide the end-user an installer (built using Client provide Installshield tool). It will contain a .NET 6.0 console app which will execute when installation occurs. Inside the Progam.cs is a Main method which creates a Registry entry for a custom URI Scheme protocol. The reason we use a .Net app (over a script) is to have it scalable, programmable and configurable.

Please suggest if this is possible? Any alternative suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol handlers are registered as registry keys. I'd recommend using the installation package to write the registry keys instead of running an executable. That way you get reference counting/rollback/updates basically all the goodness of the Windows Installer without the challenges of trying to do all that via an external executable.

Comment: "installation package to write the registry keys" - Could you link me to an example? Also what does "reference counting" mean in this context? As I mentioned, its already decided that it would be in form of a console app for the reasons provided. Do u know if console app EXE can be invoked by installer? Never tried that

Comment: InstallShield (and most other installer toolkits) use a Microsoft technology named MSI (MicroSoft Installer, I think).  It understands Windows intimately and understand what an installer must do when something is installed and uninstalled.  Among its capabilities is the creation of registry keys.  If you describe which keys need to be set, it will set them.  But, if an app is  installed multiple times (say, by different users), it will set up the keys once.  If it's then uninstalled multiple times, it will remove the keys when the last uninstall is run (ref counting).  Yes, it can run an exe